# How to Paint bitmap image to form from background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, graphics

I have a socket.BeginReceive asynchronous socket connection, which kicks off its own thread.  I am receiving a large amount of data that doesn't fit in the first pass of the method, and there is no way to know when it is done receiving as the data is many recurring xml tags.

While the data is received it is being parsed and painted onto a bitmap image in memory using graphics.fromImage(bitmap).  In order to draw this, the graphics.DrawImage(bitmap) is in my overridden paint event to allow for repainting of the form when resized, minimized, etc.

I use an Invoke call to signal to invalidate the form to kick off the paint event, which is probably not the right way to do it, which is why I am asking you folks.

The problem I'm having is that the graphics object is getting called on the thread created from the BeginReceive method, as well as the main UI thread, at the same time, throwing an exception.

Question 1:  Is there a good way to know when I have received all the data on the socket?  Keep in mind that it doesn't receive all of the data the first pass.  If so, I could then signal the paint event somehow.

or

Question 2:  Should I block the NON-UI thread somewhere to avoid the cross-thread error and then Invoke the main thread to paint the form?  If so, what is a good process for this?

Here is what I have going on for the most part:

```
private void paint_the_image()
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }));
}

// the bitmap image is created when the program loads
public void paint_bitmap(int data_type, string text, int x, int y)
{
    if (data_type == 1)
    {
        using( Graphics gr2 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap_image))
        {
           gr2.FillRectangle(
            Brushes.White, 
            35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18), 14, 18);
           gr2.DrawString(
            text, new Font("Lucida Console", 14), 
            newBrush, 35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18));
        }
    }
}

//paint event
private void main_sockets_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using(Graphics gr2 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap_image))
    {
       gr2.DrawImage(bitmap_image, 35, 200, 1500, 700);
    }
}

// this is called right after the socket connection is made.
public void wait_for_data()
{
    if (receive_callBack == null)
    {
        receive_callBack = new AsyncCallback(on_data_received);
    }
    async_result = client_socket_connect.BeginReceive(
        socket_data_buffer, 0, socket_data_buffer.Length, 
        SocketFlags.None, receive_callBack, null);        
}

public void on_data_received(IAsyncResult async)
{
    int char_count = 0;
    char_count = client_socket_connect.EndReceive(async);
    char[] chars = new char[char_count + 1];
    System.Text.Decoder decode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    int char_length = decode.GetChars(socket_data_buffer, 0, char_count, chars, 0);
     //processing data....
    paint_bitmap(1, txt.ToString(), ex, why);
    wait_for_data();
}
```

I'm new to the asynchronous connections so feel free to pick this apart.  Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: One tip: `gr2.Dispose();` don't dispose `e.Graphics` in the paint handler. This may not be your problem, but it's wrong anyway.

Comment: You have multiple bugs in your program.  You cannot encode an image in utf8, you do not get the *entire* image with just a single BeginReceive() call, you arbitrarily left required code off the paint_bitmap() method, you can't dispose objects you did not create.  Pretty hard to tackle them all in an answer, maybe it is best to leave this project on the shelf until you learn more of the basics.  Consider PictureBox.LoadAsync() instead.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for the tip! Is there a good place to call this to free up the resources?

Comment: @Brian03 you don't need to call it at all on `e.Graphics`. When you create your own `Graphics` like `Graphics.FromImage` you should wrap it in a `using` statement which will dispose it for you. You're currently leaking Graphics objects in `paint_bitmap`.

Comment: @HansPasant - thanks for the tips.  One thing though, I'm not receiving an image at all from the BeginReceive() call, it is just a text value and a location.  I'm piecing the image together as I receive the data.  Also, what required code am I missing?  thanks again...

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ahhh I see what your saying.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many bugs…where to start?

Well, let's start with your questions, focusing on the thread safety issues you see to be concerned about:

> I use an Invoke call to signal to invalidate the form to kick off the paint event, which is probably not the right way to do it

Actually, this is the expected way to deal with screen updating in Winforms: when some data changes that needs to be reflected on the screen, you invalidate the control where that data is shown, and let the control do the drawing with the `Paint` event is raised. In many cases, controls handle this all internally; e.g. `TextBox`, `Label`, `ListBox`, etc. your code generally updates the data the control is storing internally, and the control handles screen refresh.

In your case, you are drawing the bitmap directly to the screen (well, sort of…the code doesn't look like it would work, but I can infer what you *meant* to do). So the correct approach is to update the bitmap, then invalidate the control in which it's displayed so that that control's `Paint` handling can draw the bitmap to the screen.

> Is there a good way to know when I have received all the data on the socket?

That depends on what you mean by "all the data". You haven't explained your application's network protocol, so we don't know what that means. In some cases, a single TCP connection is used to transmit multiple chunks of data; in this case, the application protocol must define some kind of way to delimit those chunks. For binary protocols, this is very often a byte count that precedes the actual data. For text-based protocols, this could be special characters (e.g. '\0', newlines, LF/CR pairs, etc.) or could even be some kind of structured data (e.g. XML elements).

In other cases, "all the data" refers to every last byte sent in a single connection. In that case, you just wait for the end-of-stream indication, i.e. for the receive operation to complete with a 0 byte return value.

> The problem I'm having is that the graphics object is getting called on the thread created from the BeginReceive method, as well as the main UI thread, at the same time, throwing an exception.

As near as I can tell, the above is your primary problem. The most straightforward way to address it would be to synchronize the two threads. This does mean the UI thread could be blocked momentarily as the network I/O code is executing, but the network I/O code should be able to operate quickly enough and for brief enough moments that this wouldn't be an issue.

Synchronization might look something like this:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();

// the bitmap image is created when the program loads
public void paint_bitmap(int data_type, string text, int x, int y)
{
    if (data_type == 1)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            using( Graphics gr2 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap_image))
            {
               gr2.FillRectangle(
                Brushes.White, 
                35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18), 14, 18);
               gr2.DrawString(
                text, new Font("Lucida Console", 14), 
                newBrush, 35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18));
            }
        }
    }
}

//paint event
private void main_sockets_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap_image, 35, 200, 1500, 700);
    }
}
```

(I don't know if my change to your `Paint` event handler is exactly correct, but it surely is more correct than the code you had before, in which you were simply drawing the bitmap's contents to itself for some reason).

The above uses the `_lock` object to synchronize access to the `bitmap_image` object, ensuring that only one thread at a time is actually using it.

**<aside>**
Some points about the code example you provided: nowhere in the example do you ever actually call `paint_the_image()`, nor do you show the declaration or initialization of the `txt` variable. The `ex` and `why` variables (very poorly named by the way) are also not shown, but that seems less central to the main questions.

Bottom line: the example is far from being the [good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would be a part of *every* good Stack Overflow question, but it is especially poor in light of the omission of these key details. If you feel like you are not getting the help you need, you should take the time to clean up your question so that it is a) more focused (i.e. work on one problem at a time, and make sure you get that part working cleanly before moving on to the next issue), and b) includes the required MCVE.
**</aside>**

Now, some other thoughts about this code:

1. An alternative to the synchronization above would be to double-buffer (or even triple-buffer) your rendering. You seem to be clearing the bitmap each time anyway (which by the way you could use the `Graphics.Clear()` method for), so you don't need to preserve the image from one frame to the next.

So you could just maintain two `Bitmap` objects and draw alternately to them. You would still need synchronization, but this could be done in the form of locking in the UI thread while drawing, and locking the network I/O code only when swapping the buffers. Since swapping the buffer amounts to simply swapping the reference or even a flag or an index in an array (depending on how you implement the buffer "chain"), this is guaranteed to be quick and will never delay the UI thread for any significant amount of time.

For example:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private bool _useBufferB;

// the bitmap image is created when the program loads
public void paint_bitmap(int data_type, string text, int x, int y)
{
    if (data_type == 1)
    {
        // Note that this test is reversed from the Paint handler one
        using( Graphics gr2 =
            Graphics.FromImage(_useBufferB ? bitmap_image : bitmap_imageB))
        {
           gr2.FillRectangle(
            Brushes.White, 
            35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18), 14, 18);
           gr2.DrawString(
            text, new Font("Lucida Console", 14), 
            newBrush, 35 + (x * 14), 200 + (y * 18));
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            _useBufferB = !_useBufferB;
        }
    }
}

//paint event
private void main_sockets_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(
           _useBufferB ? bitmap_imageB : bitmap_image, 35, 200, 1500, 700);
    }
}
```

2. You have multiple problems when receiving your data.

The following code is problematic for several reasons:

```
int char_count = 0;
char_count = client_socket_connect.EndReceive(async);
char[] chars = new char[char_count + 1];
```

First, there is no reason to initialize `char_count` to `0` if you're just going to assign a new value to it in the next statement. More problematic though is that, unless you are using a single-byte character encoding (e.g. ASCII), there is no reason to expect the *byte count* returned by `EndReceive()` to correspond to a *character count*.

This is bad enough, but then you have this:

```
System.Text.Decoder decode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
int char_length = decode.GetChars(socket_data_buffer, 0, char_count, chars, 0);
```

Using a `Decoder` object can be a good thing to do. Except that you're doing it wrong. The whole point of using `Decoder` instead of just calling `Encoding.GetString()` or similar is that the `Decoder` object has an internal buffer to store incomplete character data, so that on subsequent receives it can pick up where it left off and ensure that multi-byte characters that got split across receive operations are handled correctly. When you discard the `Decoder` object and create a whole new one for each receive operation, you also discard this internal buffer and negate the benefit of using `Decoder`.

Don't do that.

Better might be something like this:

```
private readonly Decoder _decoder = new Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

public void on_data_received(IAsyncResult async)
{
    int byte_count = client_socket_connect.EndReceive(async);
    char[] chars = new char[_decoder.GetCharCount(socket_data_buffer, 0, byte_count)];

    _decoder.GetChars(socket_data_buffer, 0, byte_count, chars, 0);

     //processing data....
    paint_bitmap(1, new string(chars), ex, why);
    wait_for_data();
}
```

Though granted, without a good code example it's impossible to know for sure that's exactly the right thing (i.e. do you really want to just pass the decoded text straight to the `paint_bitmap()` method, or did you intend to further process that text first?).

3. Of course, at some point you will definitely want to introduce a call to the `paint_the_image()` method. After all, without that the UI thread won't know to redraw anything.
4. Maybe this comment should have been first…I don't know. I just wanted to get all of the above out of the way, since you'll need to know that stuff anyway if you want to use these techniques later.

But, really: I'm wondering why you are using a `Bitmap` for all this anyway. All you seem to be doing is copying text data to the bitmap, and Winforms does have a variety of other text-friendly controls you could use to do that. Even a simple `TextBox` (set `Multiline` to `true` for logging multiple lines, set `ReadOnly` to `true` if you want the use to not be able modify the contets), or a `ListBox`, or `RichTextBox`, or `Label`, or…

There are lots of choices, all of which easier and probably more efficient than handling your own bitmap buffer to render into.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice, it is very helpful.  To clear up my 2nd question about the socket.  I am receiving multiple chunks and I am parsing them as they come across, storing the partial xml tags.  I was hoping for a creative way to know when I get all tags, since there is no root tag.  I didn't write the server side and I have to adapt to it, but I can see there really isn't a way so I think using the 'lock' statement will help here.  #2 I didn't call 'paint_the_image()' as I didnt know where to and was hoping for some advice on that.  I think I figured that part out. :)

Comment: @Brian03: without a complete code example showing the full receiving and parsing/processing code, as well as a complete description of the data format, it's impossible to offer specific advice. In terms of parsing XML, unfortunately .NET doesn't include an XML parser that does well with parsing multiple fragments in a single stream. But depending on what guarantees (if any) the server provides in terms of how it formats the XML fragments, it could be relatively simple to write your own parser. It would likely not work with general XML, but only the "flavor" that server sends.

Comment: thanks again....I didn't really think what I do with it after I receive it is important.  I found a way to parse it just fine, I was just curious if there was a way to know when it is all received...for instance, when the socket is sitting idle.  I dont think there is a good way though, so I'll have to figure something else out.  thanks again!